# Should home users just turn on the firewall?

Tags: networking, security, firewall

I'm using Ubuntu desktop and I want to know if any extra configuration is needed to secure my system.

I know that in the documentation it says that this is ok, but I read on a site that while `ufw` is enabled all the ports stay open.

So I think sufficiently secure settings for home users are

- input blocked
- output allowed

I want to know whether the internal rules and settings need to be changed.
I am thinking that these options are not functioning, due to lack of configuration on ports etc.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use `ufw` as your firewall on your system, then might I suggest that you use `gufw` with it so that you can configure it based on your needs.

To install `gufw` type in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install gufw
```

Then to run it, type in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo gufw
```

You should see a screen like the following that will allow you to configure your firewall as you need.

[image]

You can scroll up and down the Getting started screen on the Home tab to help explain more of what you can set for your `ufw` configuration.

More information can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped me !! thank you so much!
I am new to the linux world and I do not understand anything about ports even on windows.
But how do I know which door to close or open? Should I forget this and not change anything? Do you know any website for me to learn about it?

Comment: @J.PP It really all depends on what you want to do with your system.  You can run a video server, game server (like Minecraft), general file sharing.  It all depends on what you want to do.  There are things like Webmin, that is a web based administration tool for your system that relies on port 10000 to be open.  OpenSSH server normally uses ports 22 and 443.  Plex video server normally defaults to port 32400.   For documentation, just look around.  Start with Google.  There is TONS out there for you!  The sky is the limit!